# Can I add settings option in a Floating Action Button (FAB)?

Tags: android, material-design, user-experience, floating-action-button

I'm developing a **material design** app. I want to know that can I add settings option in a `Floating Action` Button?

Like when user press the button (`FAB`), settings will be opened. Would this be a good user experience?

I know this question is framed quiet badly, but I didn't find a better way.

Please cooperate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends on your screen, but in general "Open settings" is not an action worth a FAB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't recommend that. According to Google guidelines, Settings can be shown in the following ways(Please refer the url) https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/settings.html#settings-grouping-settings.

And FAB is used for a promoted action. By promoted action means, an action of more priority, which eases a most used action(say, 'Compose' in Gmail).(Please refer this url)
https://www.google.co.in/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-floating-action-button

And, of course you can decide where to keep these sort of thing. Ultimately you are the owner of your app :). But these guidelines are good to follow since it will meet a common user's expectation. Ultimately, UX matters ... :)